# How to do restorecon -f recursively?

Tags: selinux

I have tried both with a file and using standard input, and it seems it is impossible to get `restorecon -r -f [file|-]` to do anything at all. Is this possible?

Comment: Assuming the `-R` switch doesn't work with `-f`? You've tried that, right?

Comment: The `-r` and `-R` switches are identical according to the `man` page. But out of desperation I did try it :/

Comment: I figured you did but wanted to ask...